# TFS 2017 release management log window not working

Tags: tfs

I am using TFS 2017 update 2 on premise for CD .Log window is not working when i open the log for the completed release. Please refer the below screenshot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAD79.jpg

"Advanced Code Editor " Extension is enabled.Let me know how to proceed on this

Comment: I have tested TFS 2017.2 instance but could not reproduce the issue. Found this thread discussing the issue which might help you https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/30476/tfs-2017-update-1-build-step-logs-are-blank.html

Comment: Hi, any update on this issue, have you figured it out?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look in the _admin/_extensions page, if there list the Advanced Code Editor Extension already.

Try to disable and then re-enable it, see if it do the trick.

If above step do not work, try to directly delete the extension, this left the Legacy Extensions area empty. Finally check the release log window again.

---

**Update**

Reinstall the Legacy Extension,all you have to do is this:

Create a **`manifest.xml`** file with the following contents:

```
<Extension name="Advanced Code Editor Extension" id="{70D19AD3-93FA-437B-8CCE-CD80AA405F69}" version="1.0" min-host-version="11">
    <Description>Provides advanced source control file and diff viewers to TFS</Description>
    <Vendor>Microsoft</Vendor>
    <Integrations>
      <Frame end-point="tfs.source-control.file-viewer" url="{TfsRootPath}_BuiltInExtensions/_CodeEditor/Edit">
        <Properties>
          <Property name="name" value="Advanced Code Editor"/>
        </Properties>
      </Frame>
      <Frame end-point="tfs.source-control.diff-viewer" url="{TfsRootPath}_BuiltInExtensions/_CodeEditor/Diff">
        <Properties>
          <Property name="name" value="Advanced Code Editor"/>
        </Properties>
      </Frame>
    </Integrations>  
  </Extension>
```

Then go to your `[tfs-url]/tfs/_admin/_extensions` page and at Legacy Extensions pick the `manifest.xml` file. The Advance Code Editor will get installed. (again). Enable it and check if the issues are gone.

Comment: I tried the steps,no luck. After uninstalling ,i am seeing blank screen.

Comment: @user3744418  Have you tried some other Releases and release definition ? Did this issue also occurs  on them? Moreover, what's the result if  others check the log in their own machine?  This will narrow down the issue.

Comment: PatrickLu-MSFT , After uninstalling the extension,i am seeing blank screen in log screen. I have tried with other release definitions. Tried with other login also. Now we are seeing blank screen only

Comment: Hi @user3744418 , if the log window is blank for everyone, try to reinstall the Advanced Code Editor Extension again and then enable, more details about how to please see my update answer.